# JavaScript - How do I learn about "closures" usage?

Tags: javascript, closures

From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia: **Closure (computer science)**

> In computer science, a closure is a
>   function that is evaluated in an
>   environment containing one or more
>   bound variables. When called, the
>   function can access these variables.
>   The explicit use of closures is
>   associated with functional programming
>   and with languages such as ML and
>   Lisp. Constructs such as objects in
>   other languages can also be modeled
>   with closures.

To use this inside of JavaScript, can someone point me to an example of how this applies?

Comment: I've just written a [blog post](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2010/11/a-brief-introduction-to-closures/) about closures in JavaScript that you may find helfpul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(using an example from jQuery)

```
function SetClassOnHover(className){
  $("td").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).addClass(className);
    },
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass(className);
    }
  );
}
```

The closure comes into play when the variable className is used inside the scope of each function.  When SetClassOnHover exits, both functions must retain a handle on className in order to access its value when the functions are called.  That's what the closure enables.

Comment: This is the most succinctly useful closure example I've seen.  Nice.

Comment: This answer, IMO, sucks. this is 10% of what closures can do. Why not show private variables with it? At least answer it without using jquery...

Comment: @invisible nothing stopping you from answering.  How about you stop talking big and start acting?

Comment: well... it's a little late but fine.

Answer (score 11):

Searching for "javascript closures" gave plenty of encouraging-looking links. The top three were these two (the third link was a reformatted version of the second):

- [Javascript closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html)
- [JavaScript closures for dummies](http://web.archive.org/web/20101113013100/http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html)

If these didn't help you, please explain why so we're in a better position to actually help. If you didn't search before asking the question, well - please do so next time :)

Comment: @sunglim: It would have helped if you'd said *which* link wasn't valid. Anyway, fixing.

Comment: Links 1 and 3 are the same article.

Comment: Anyone can google "encouraging" links, but the user was looking for direction from the OS community.  If you haven't used the resources yourself don't recommend them.

Comment: @Yarin: The OP *specifically* asked for "an example of how this applies". The linked pages give plenty of examples. While anyone *can* search for links, it seems to me that lots of people *don't*. I think you meant that 2 and 3 are the same article - albeit reformatted. I'll remove the third link.

Answer (score 1):

A practical example of closures is when they are used to create "Private" variables, like

```
function incrementer(){
    var i=0;
    this.increment=function(){
        i++;
    }
    this.get=function(){
        return i;
    }
}
```

The only way to access i is to use the method get, and the only way to change it is to use the method increment. In classes, you can do this to emulate private variables.