# What are Closures and Callbacks?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

What are closures and callbacks in JavaScript? I've yet to find a good explanation of either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095707/what-is-the-exact-definition-of-a-closure

Comment: Did you try this in google: "closure javascript site:stackoverflow.com"  (Don't bother with the search box in SO itself its rubbish)  There are loads of places where closures are described

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work

Comment: Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615907/how-is-a-closure-different-from-a-callback

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Closures** have already been well handled in Stackoverflow here is just a selection:-

[How does a javascript closure work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work)
[What exactly does “closure” refer to in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801957/what-exactly-does-closure-refer-to-in-javascript)
[can you say this is a right example of Javascript Closure.. Where the places we need to consider avoiding the closures??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055641/can-you-say-this-is-a-right-example-of-javascript-closure-where-the-places-we-n)
[JavaScript scope and closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631187/javascript-scope-and-closure)
[Javascript Closures and ‘this’ context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346015/javascript-closures-and-this-context)
[JavaScript - How do I learn about “closures” usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212401/javascript-how-do-i-learn-about-closures-usage)

**Callbacks** are a simpler concept.  A callback is basically where a function accepts another function as a parameter.  At some point during execution the called function will execute the function passed as a parameter, this is a *callback*.  Quite often the callback actually happens as an asynchronous event, in which case the called function may return without having executed the callback, that may happen later.  Here is a common (browser based) example:-

```
 function fn() { alert("Hello, World"); }
 window.setTimeout(fn, 5000);
```

Here the function `fn` is passed as a *callback* to the `setTimeout` function.  Set timeout returns immediately however 5 seconds later the function passed as a *callback* is executed.

**Closures and callbacks**

Quite often the reason that closures get created (either incidentally, accidentally or deliberately) is the need to create a callback.  For example:-

```
 function AlertThisLater(message, timeout)
 {
     function fn() { alert(message); }
     window.setTimeout(fn, timeout);
 }

 AlertThisLater("Hello, World!", 5000);
```

(Please read some of the linked posts to grasp closures)

A closure is created containing in part the `message` parameter, `fn` is executed quite some time after the call to `AlertThisLater` has returned, yet `fn` still has access to the original content of `message`.

Comment: Are callbacks most commonly used with setTimeout?

Comment: setTimeout is a common usage but equally common would be `onreadystatechange` on the `XmlHttpRequest` object.  You will also see extensive usage of callbacks in code that uses Javascript frameworks such as JQuery.  In many of these cases the callback is just where you would provide a little logic to customise a large but otherwise standard process.  Also callbacks are frequently used to execute the same function over a set of objects.