# Google Maps API v3 - Geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i would like to get a map with 2 markers. if i use the LatLng (see JS Code /*WORKS JUST FINE*/) it is no problem... but as soon i try to use geocoding (see JS Code /*Y U NOT WORKING?*/) it doesn't work. I guess this is all wrong:

*var adresse3=geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern'})[0].geometry.location;*

Can anyone help me. Thanks you in advance.

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(47.050944,8.309441);
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize(){  
    var mapProp = {
      center            :myCenter         
    };
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    /*WORKS JUST FINE*/
    var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.050944,8.309441)
    });
    marker1.setMap(map);
    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:"marker1"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow1.open(map,marker1);
    });  
    /*Y U NOT WORKING?*/
    var adresse3=geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern'})[0].geometry.location;
    var marker3=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: adresse3
    });
    marker3.setMap(map);
    var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:"marker3"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
        infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
    }); 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats how i solved it (i used the goMap PlugIn http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/ )

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gomap-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){ 
        $("#googleMap").goMap({ 
            address: 'Luzern, Schweiz', 
            zoom: 13,
            maptype: 'ROADMAP',
            mapTypeControl: false,  
            hideByClick: false
        }); 
        $.goMap.createMarker({  
            address: 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern',
            html: 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern' 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

now it works just fine...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that geocoder.geocode is asynchronous, so you have to pass a [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks).

Adapted from the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) :

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern'}, function(results, status)     {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas, you have an error in line:

```
geocoder.geocode('address': 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern', function(results, status)
```

use this code:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': 'Winkelriedstrasse 47, 6004 Luzern'}, function(results, status)
```