# How to use external rest api in Sails js (nodejs MVC)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, real-time, sails.js

Im using sailsjs as a MVC  for node js, i'm still learning it.
I managed to get data from my own database and use it.

But now i need/want to get data from an external rest api.
I used this in my controller:

```
// api/controllers/SomeController.js
test : function(res,req){
    var j;

    var https = require('https');

    var options = {
      hostname: 'testing.atlassian.net',
      port: 443,
      path: '/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=ABC',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'SuperSecretLoginAndPassword'}
    };

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function(d) {

      });
     });

    req.end();
}
```

The variable `d` is displaying the right result.
How can i use the request results in my view?
I've searched a lot but i cant find any ways to display this in my view.

And will this be realtime updated? So if something in de rest api changes I won't have to refresh.

Sorry if this is something stupid.

Comment: You may want to change your password now.

Comment: Its a real name but it was a fake password just made to test this :D but thanks :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you'll want to wait for your request to fire its callback and then feed the fetched data into `res.locals`. Assuming you are fetching JSON data, you could do this:

```
// api/controllers/SomeController.js
test: function(req, res) {
  var https = require('https');

  ...

  https.request(options, function(response) {
    var responseData = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

    response.on('data', function(chunk){
      responseData += chunk;
    });

    response.once('error', function(err){
      // Some error handling here, e.g.:
      res.serverError(err);
    });

    response.on('end', function(){
      try {
        // response available as `responseData` in `yourview`
        res.locals.requestData = JSON.parse(responseData);
      } catch (e) {
        sails.log.warn('Could not parse response from options.hostname: ' + e);
      }

      res.view('yourview');
    });
  }).end();

}
```

**The example code you supplied has some issues:**

- `test: function(res,req) ...` Don't mixup the controller arguments, the first is _req_uest, the second one _res_ponse.
- `var req = https.request ...` You really do not want to override the `req` argument passed into your controller action. Use some other name.
- `https.request(options, function(res) {...}` Same here. Doing this overrides `res` for the `https.request` callback scope - preventing you from using all the goodies (e.g.: `res.view`) supplied by the `res` parameter passed to your controller.

I'd guess it would make sense for you to read up on closures and callbacks:

[What are Closures and Callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks)

Comment: That seems to do it! Thanks and i will check the closures and callbacks link.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are doing a lot of request to third parties you could use [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler#example-usage) to make your life a bit easier.