# Javascript store data into variables from same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a div in which there is a number that constantly changes. For instance:

```
<div id="current">124</div>
```

Then I have a JavaScript function to grab the data from this field and store it into a JavaScript variable. Because the number constantly changes, I delay the code and store the NEW number (after five seconds) into another variable.

However, when I look at the data stored in both of the variables, they are exactly the same (when the number in the div has changed). How can I change my code to store the content of the div in one variable, and store the content again (but five seconds later) in another variable?

```
var before = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;
setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);
var after = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);`???? Here is a nice reference on how to use `setTimeout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there some way to introduce a delay in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24849/is-there-some-way-to-introduce-a-delay-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var after;
var before = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;

setTimeout(function(){
   after = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;
}, 5000);
```

**Why is this?**

Your usage of `setTimeout` does (almost) nothing. Your code step by step:

1. assign `before`
2. Setup empty anonymous callback to the be executed after 5000ms
3. assing `after`
4. After 5000ms the anonymous callback is executed, doing nothing at all

The suggested code step by step;

1. create `after`
2. assing `before`
   3  Setup anonymous function to the be executed after 5000ms
3. After 5000ms the callback function is executed, assigning `after` from the outer scope to `document.getElementById('current').innerHTML`

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/bE5Jd/1/

You probably should read up on [closures and callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/javascript-closures-and-callbacks).

Comment: This assumes you access `after` after the timeout has fired, you probably should add the code that depends on the assignment of `after`

Comment: To follow up on this: the easiest way to ensure your code uses the correct value would be to execute it in the setTimeout callback.

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) does not mean "delaying the code after".

Try this:

```
var before = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML, after;
setTimeout(function(){
    after = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout` function will create a new "thread" executing the function passed, and then continue with the current "thread" (In quotes because they are not truly threads, but the result is similar to threading).

This means 5 seconds have not passed between the assignment of `before` and `after`.  Try this instead:

```
var after, before = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;
setTimeout(function(){
  after = document.getElementById('current').innerHTML;
}, 5000);
```