# React closure with callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading this React related [article](https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578). I have also looked at the discussion on closures and callbacks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930272/javascript-closures-vs-anonymous-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070275/what-are-closures-and-callbacks).

In an example, given in the React related article, there are three components `<App>, <Form>, <Button>`. `<App>` passes a state value to `<Form>` component during initialization and also during `componentDidMount` lifecycle. `<Form>` passes a callback function to `<Button>` component along with the state value it received from `<App>`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { val: "one" }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ val: "two" })
  }

  render() {
    return <Form value={this.state.val} />
  }
}

const Form = props => (
  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      alert(props.value)
    }}
  />
)
```

When the button is clicked in the below `<Button>` component, it alerts a stale value "one" instead of the latest value "two".

```
class Button extends React.Component {
.....
  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>This one is stale</button>
    )
  }
}
```

The reason given in the React article for stale value is that the callback closes over props.value.

I do not understand how/why is the props.value being closed over in React component. The callback assignment in above  is probably being done like this:

```
this.props.onClick = () => {
      alert(props.value)
    }
```

So why is the latest value not being picked up?
How is the prop.value "closed over"?

The complete code is given [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-nash-thw9y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete code for the `Button` component:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>This one is stale</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>This one works</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `Button` component is set up to not rerender when passed new props, thus `this.props.onClick` will only be evaluated once on initial render and will always reference the first `onClick` function that was passed to it.

In contrast, even though it is also evaluated once, `() => this.props.onClick()` is set up to look up `onClick` on the component current `props` at the time the arrow function is actually executed. At that point, the `props` will have been updated with the new version of `onClick`.

Comment: Are you saying that in the first case the `props.value` in `alert(props.value)` will be substituted with "one" -  like `this.props.onClick = () => alert("one")`

Comment: No. `Form` will render twice, each time with a different set of props and passing `Button` a different `onClick` function. Each `onClick` function closes over - ie keeps a reference to - the `props` passed to `Form` at the time of render - so `props.value` will always evaluate to `"one"` for the first `onClick` function, and `"two"` for the second.

Comment: But ultimately, the reason why you're seeing the result that you see is because `Button` is set up to never rerender.

Comment: What exactly does "closes over" mean, is it substitution of values ?

Comment: It just means that a function captures and keeps a live reference to something - more specifically a variable that is in scope at declaration time. This is important because in javascript, functions can be executed in a different scope than the one in which they are declared.